# find the largest area of a circle inside a square

Tags: geometry

Can anyone help me on this? I tried to solve the problem by drawing two straight lines (SU an NU) and use basic geometry. It didn't work. Thank you very much!

Problem: Square SQUA with midpoints M and N of sides SQ and SA, respectively, has an area of 64 square units. What is the number of square units, rounded to the nearest integer, in the area of the largest circle which can be drawn in pentagon MNAUQ?

[image]

Answer (score 2):

The side length of the square is $8$ units. The biggest circle will happen when its center is on the diagonal due to symmetry.

Let $MN$ mets the circle at $X$. Construct a line parallel to $SQ$ through $X$. Construct a line through the centre of the circle parallel to $QU$. Let these two lines cross at $Y$. The distance from $Y$ to the edge $SQ$ is $\frac14$ the width, i.e. $2$ units. The distance from $Y$ to centre of the circle is $\frac{r}{\sqrt{2}}$ (due to the $45^\circ$ angle).

Hence:

$$8=2+\frac{r}{\sqrt2}+r$$
$$6=r\left(1+\frac{1}{\sqrt2}\right)$$
$$r=\frac{6\sqrt{2}}{1+\sqrt2}$$

Answer (score 1):

Call the midpoint of $MN\ R$.  The center of the circle is on $RU$ by symmetry.  Use the fact that the distance from the center of the circle to $R$ and to $QU is the same.